# How to read multiple partitioned .gzip files into a Spark Dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following folder of partitioned data-

```
my_folder
 |--part-0000.gzip
 |--part-0001.gzip
 |--part-0002.gzip
 |--part-0003.gzip
```

I try to read this data into a dataframe using-

```
>>> my_df = spark.read.csv("/path/to/my_folder/*")
>>> my_df.show(5)
+--------------------+
|                 _c0|
+--------------------+
|��[I���...|
|��RUu�[*Ք��g��T...|
|�t���  �qd��8~��...|
|�(���b4�:������I�...|
|���!y�)�PC��ќ\�...|
+--------------------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

Also tried using this to check the data-

```
>>> rdd = sc.textFile("/path/to/my_folder/*")
>>> rdd.take(4)
['\x1f�\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00�͎\\ǖ�7�~�\x04�\x16��\'��"b�\x04�AR_<G��"u��\x06��L�*�7�J�N�\'�qa��\x07\x1ey��\x0b\\�\x13\x0f\x0c\x03\x1e�Q��ڏ�\x15Y_Yde��Y$��Q�JY;s�\x1d����[��\x15k}[B\x01��ˀ�PT��\x12\x07-�\x17\x12�\x0c#\t���T۱\x01yf��\x14�S\x0bc)��\x1ex���axAO˓_\'��`+HM҈�\x12�\x17�@']
```

**NOTE**: When I do a `zcat part-0000.gzip | head -1` to read the file content, it shows the data is tab separated and in plain readable English.

How do I read these files properly into a dataframe?

Comment: Is your gzip files are in xml format? If so you you should use xml package.

Comment: hi open sample file in notepad/text editor you will understand kind of file. If its XML see following link and check python API https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml

Comment: @Sri_Karthik i opened the file and looks like it's a tab separated file and not in XML format..

Comment: If its not xml file then it should read data as per your code my_df = spark.read.csv("/path/to/my_folder/", sep= '\t'). I do not understand why its showing in different format. May be some problem with encoding. So check encoding of your data. By default it will be utf-8. Can you show an image or any random  5 lines of your data as sample?

Comment: Why not do .csv(..., compression='gzip') instead? it is supported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, Spark does not recognize the `.gzip` file extension. So I had to change the file extensions before reading the partitioned data-

```
import os

# go to my_folder
os.chdir("/path/to/my_folder")

# renaming all `.gzip` extensions to `.gz` within my_folder
cmd = 'rename "s/gzip/gz/" *.gzip'
result_code = os.system(cmd)

if result_code == 0:
    print("Successfully renamed the file extensions!")

    # finally reading the data into a dataframe
    my_df = spark.read.csv("/path/to/my_folder/*", sep="\t")
else:
    print("Could not rename the file extensions!")
```

Comment: Why not do `.csv(..., compression='gzip')` instead? it is supported